# rspec rails testing session_id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, rspec

I have a quite peculiar thing to test.
Recently we have changed from cookie-storage to active-record-storage when it comes to storing session information. This was done in order to prevent using session_id from cookies to continue browsing session even after users was logged out (That's a thing you need to sadly accept when using cookie-storage).

Now I need to write some code to test whether moving to active-record-storage indeed fixed that security issue but I dont know how.

The scenario is that:

user `signs in` to the app

users `signs out` of the app

`session_id` from the request header is then used in get request to view a part of the app that normally needs authentication
this should not be possible, because we are not authenticated(although we use the session_id from the previous request)

we get a 401, or 404 or anything else than 200 hopefully.

So far I have managed to get the session_id from the request ->
`@request.env["rack.sesion.options"][:id]`

but I don't know how to use and put this `session_id` into next request

any ideas?

Comment: have you tried the [rack_session_access](https://github.com/railsware/rack_session_access) ?

Comment: no, but it seems like a nice gem exactly for my case. Will give it a try!

Comment: Are you using `reset_session` in your logout method?

Comment: no, I'm not using it

Comment: Well thats your problem - not SessionStorage.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are slightly misstaken. If done correctly a logout even using the cookie-storage is permanent.

> A session usually consists of a hash of values and a session id,
>   usually a 32-character string, to identify the hash. Every cookie sent
>   to the client's browser includes the session id. And the other way
>   round: the browser will send it to the server on every request from
>   the client.
>   [The Rails Guides - Securing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#what-are-sessions-questionmark)

So to invalidate the users sessions on logout you want to call `reset_session`. This issues a new session id and invalidates the old one - on the server.

> session_id from the request header is then used in get request to view
>   a part of the app that normally needs authentication this should not
>   be possible, because we are not authenticated(although we use the
>   session_id from the previous request)

Using `reset_session` renders the above scenario impossible since rails will no longer accept the old session id. When using cookie-storage this means that the users cookies containing the old session id will no longer be accepted - the same basic principle applies to the other session storage mechanisms. Except that for some sessions stores the stale data may be removed as well.

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    reset_session # prevents session fixation
    @user = User.find(params[:email])
    if @user.try(:authenticate, params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = @user.id
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      render :new, status: :not_found
    end
  end

  def destroy
    reset_session
    redirect_to root_path
  end
end
```

> The most effective countermeasure [against session fixation] is to
>   issue a new session identifier and declare the old one invalid after a
>   successful login. That way, an attacker cannot use the fixed session
>   identifier. This is a good countermeasure against session hijacking,
>   as well.
>   [The Rails Guides - Securing Rails Applications](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-fixation-countermeasures)

### How to test it?

The easiest and cleanest way is to use a feature spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'
RSpec.feature "User Authentiation" do

  context "signing out" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before do
      visit new_session_path
      fill_in :email, with: user.email
      fill_in :password: with: user.password
      click_button 'Log in'
      click_button 'Log out'
    end

    scenario 'user should not be signed in' do
      expect(page).to have_link 'Sign in'
      expect(page).to_not have_link 'Sign Out'
    end

    scenario 'user should not be able to access the member area' do
      visit '/members-only'
      expect(current_path).to_not eq '/members-only'
      expect(page).to have_text 'Please sign in'
    end
  end

  # ...
end
```

This avoids testing the underlying session mechanism and instead focuses on testing the behavior of your application.

If you need a lower level test than use a request spec. Don't use a controller spec as they fake the whole request and rack layer.

Comment: hi -> I have already tried using reset_session when we used cookie store, but mayb I was doing it wrong?
Will try to go through your answer and check how it works and update about the outcome. thanks for such extensive reply

Comment: hello, in response to your answer -> I have put the reset_session in the destroy action in our session_controller(its actually a devise session controller)
how did I verify that it doesn't help in my situation?

Comment: 1. log in to the application
2. turn on developer tools in chrome -> network
3. log out of the app
4. in network tab of dev tools I look for the sign_out packet/cookie/file (im not sure how technically it is called)
5. in the sign_out header in the Cookie section i see my session_id (my_app_name_session)
6. I copy it and turn on the chrom rest client that lets me send REST requests
7. I fill the Cookie section in my REST GET request that I shoot into my app url that requires users to be authenticated

Comment: 8. I get response with 200 OK and the parsed response is html output of the view I was aiming to

If you see any errors in my method of checking this please do correct me